# Should you have a separate database for managing users in .net core API microservice?

Tags: asp.net-core, microservices

I am trying to design a simple microservice application. In a large application where application screens are shown to user based on roles.

> Is it a good idea to design a separate user database and create user service to authenticate users.

System Details:
Lets say I have 2 microservices designed in .net core 3.1
**Product Service and Orders Service.**

Authentication of requests will be managed by API gateway-Ocelot service. User service will be generating token and passing it on to front end who will call my gateway- ocelot which will call Product and Orders service.

I am just focusing on user database for this question scope. Below is what i found so far

> Force users to use Azure AD. This way you don't have to manage a separate database

> Have user table in both Product and Orders database. This way authorization based on roles will be convenient but here you will be violating microservices concept and duplicating user code.

Comment: In my opinion, this should based on your requirement. If you there is no need for building your own user login system. You could choose Azure AD. If you have your own user login sys, you should create a new service which contains its own database as mciroservice.

Comment: We have our own user system basically current application uses microsoft membership module to manage users. having a separate User database would be a good idea in this case?